# How to set EnableEventValidation to false?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I really need to turn `EnableEventValidation` off just for one particular form / one site. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

I would really appreciate some help, this is pretty urgent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can disable event validation for an entire site in the web.config file.(Not recommend!!! Do not use this method as it is not safe for your site)

```
 <system.web>

   <pages enableEventValidation="false"/>

</system.web>
```

Alternatively, we can disable validation for a single page.

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" ... %>
```

It is strongly recommended that you do not disable event validation. If you do disable event validation, make sure that no postback could be constructed that could have an unintended effect on your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just simplifying my page and not using the script that was causing the problems. I tried disabling it for just the form in SharePoint designer but it kept crashing my page so I just ended up not using it. Thanks for replying though!